# completing-read-default auto-focus candidate window

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

How to automatically set focus to window with displayed candidates (after tab punch) in default emacs read with autocompletion?

I can not use IDO nor other autocompletion systems in my case because I need to browse through 80k+ candidates, and only autocompletion system which can handle this is the default one.

I will be glad for any useful pointers.

EDIT

After some research, I get to work following imperfect solution:

```
(define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map
    (kbd "<tab>")
    (lambda ()
      (interactive)
      (call-interactively 'minibuffer-complete)
      (call-interactively 'switch-to-completions)))
(define-key completion-list-mode-map
    (kbd "C-f")
    'isearch-forward)
```

Only problem is, after I enter completing-read-default, I must first hit TAB to open window with candidates (with newly added autofocus). But I want it to open window with candidates immediately without need to hit TAB. How to do it? I tried to call minibuffer-complete after call to completing-read-default but it doesnt opened window with candidates, only standard minibuffer prompt.

Comment: Provide a recipe, at least partial, starting from `emacs -Q`, to show what you are doing. Show clearly what you want to happen, contrasting it with what is happening now.

Comment: Wouldn't the [emacs stackexchange](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/) be better suited for this question?

Comment: LinFelix I think, yes, mistakes happens...

Comment: Drew I added edit which will hopefully clarifies my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some pain, I finally found solution

```
(defun custom/default-completing-read (question candidates)
  (run-at-time "0.5" nil
               (lambda ()
                 (minibuffer-complete)
                 (switch-to-completions)
                 (isearch-forward)))
  (completing-read-default question candidates))
```

After call, it invokes default (written in C) completion system which can handle tons and tons of candidates without problems with automatic jump into candidate selection with `isearch-forward` enabled.

Hope it will help someone in future ...